# iTunes: Failed to create an app icon

Tags: iphone, ipad, icons, itunes

I am having this problem today when I tried to update my iPad app in iTunes. First it asked me to upload an application icon (which already existed, but they needed other), 1024 X 1024. I have uploaded non-alpha, non-layered, no-transparency image, upload succeeded. But when I hit "Save" it continuously gives me: "Failed to create an app icon error." I have tried png, jpg, same error. There is no other, detailed info on this error. Anybody can help me what is going wrong? Never had this problem before.

Comment: ditto, could they want 2048x2048 now?

Comment: rowdyruckus, apple says that the image must be 1024 x 1024

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with IC.  Itunesconnect is getting worse and worse. I switched the browser, then it works.  the same image file!

Comment: Using Safari solves the problem for me - I was getting this error while using Chrome

Answer (score 21):

So here is what worked for me:

I used Chrome, but waited a minute AFTER uploading the icon, BEFORE pressing the save button.

My theory: I was pressing save immediately after the upload preview icon appeared. Perhaps the icon preview area displayed a thumbnail of the icon on the screen before the upload had been completely processed in the iTunes Connect backend.

Hope this works for someone else.

Comment: Hell. This worked! iTC has been worse than ever. Thanks!

Comment: I left it overnight and hit Save again this morning - fixed. That was driving me insane!

Comment: safari solved the problem while waiting is very expensive operation :)

Comment: Second try after the 20 seconds wait fixed the problem in Safari

Answer (score 8):

Same Problem, changed to Firefox and it got fixed. I was working with Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Safari choked, Chrome worked perfectly. Irony.

Answer (score 3):

Switching to Chrome fixed the problem for me. Usually I only use Safari for iTunes Connect. iTunes Connect often doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: i try with chrome, safari and firefox, same error :(

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem on Chrome but when i switch browser to Firefox it worked

Comment: same for me, didn't work on chrome but worked on firefox

Answer (score 2):

Faced this issue today on Safari version 8.0.6. I waited for over a minute after uploading the icon and then tried saving. Did not help.

I then tired it on Google Chrome (version 42.0.2311.152 (64-bit)) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me this morning 10-16-2014,  Apple fixed the issue by 4:00pm.  I just got it to upload with the same icon as before.  It seems to be working now with a 1024x1024

Comment: still not working for me. @user4151735 did you do anything special?

Comment: It still wasn't working for me either. I switched browsers (to Chrome) and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me over firefox

Answer (score 1):

I know this is some time now after the initial post but just to confirm that this is still happening occasionally. Would not work in Safari (would have thought an Apple website would work in an Apple browser!) but works perfectly in Chrome!
Come on Apple, get a grip!

Answer (score 0):

Like user4151735 stated, the problem has been resolved itself. Just now I tried to Save with the exact same image, everything went OK. Looks like Apple server had some issue today afternoon, at least till 5:30PM EST.

Comment: Still screwed up for me but yes, it's definitely an Apple issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need more time.
In my case, In last friday I had a happened same bug.
but this monday, No problem.

I think that Apple Ituness Connect's Bug.